# Change the TextColor of Individual ListBox items in PowerShell (Winforms)

Tags: powershell, textcolor

How can I change the text color?  This Code works very well with the backgroundcolor.

```
$listBox_DrawItem=
{
    param([System.Object] $sender, [System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs] $e)
    if ($Sender.Items.Count -eq 0) {return}
    $lbItem=$Sender.Items[$e.Index]
    if ( $lbItem -match "n/a Platzhalter")  
    { 
        $Color=[System.Drawing.Color]::green  
        try
        {
            $brush = new-object System.Drawing.SolidBrush($Color)
            $e.Graphics.FillRectangle($brush, $e.Bounds)
        }
        finally
        {
            $brush.Dispose()
        }
    }
    $e.Graphics.DrawString($lbItem, $e.Font, [System.Drawing.SystemBrushes]::ControlText, (new-object System.Drawing.PointF($e.Bounds.X, $e.Bounds.Y)))
}
```